# Is ngOnInIt Called when a *ngFor loops again?

Tags: angular, typescript

There's nothing really wrong with my code, but I am just trying to understand how ngOnInit actually functions.

Look at this simple HTML code.

```html
<ul class="list-group">
      <a
        class="list-group-item"
        style="cursor: pointer"
        *ngFor="let ingredient of ingredients">
        {{ ingredient.name }} ({{ ingredient.amount }})
      </a>
</ul>
```

If the amount of `ingredients` changes, will `ngOnInit` be called again?

This is my typescript code for the same component.

```js
export class ShoppingListComponent implements OnInit {
  ingredients: Ingredient[]
  
  constructor(private shoppingListSerivce: ShoppingList) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.ingredients = this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredients
    this.shoppingListSerivce.ingredientAdded.subscribe(
      (ingredient: Ingredient) => this.shoppingListSerivce.addIngredient(ingredient)
    )
  }
  }
```

So will `ngOnInIt` be called when `ingredients` change? Or is that not how this works?

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: No, a change of `ingredients` won't trigger `ngOnInit`

Answer (score 1):

Simply no,
`ngOnInit` runs once when the component loads. If you use a subcomponent for the `a` element, which also implements `ngOnInit` then yes, if the list grows, the new list elements render and their `ngOnInit` will fire.
But your parent list component won't re-init.

Comment: Well for instance, when I change `ingredients` , do you perhaps know how `ngOnInIt` knows how to update the new value of `ingredients`?

Comment: Not the `ngOnInit` knows this, Angular has a change detection strategy. If you made a change, then Angular spies these changes and applies them on the DOM (very simple explanation). There are different lifecycle hooks (functions) that represent this change detection process.

Comment: Check this https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#lifecycle-event-sequence
or this
https://angular.io/guide/change-detection#angular-change-detection-and-runtime-optimization

Comment: so you're saying that ngOnInIt has nothing to do with this, and that is one of Angular's behind the scenes of how it updates properties regardless of the lifecycle hook? So if I had used `ngOnChanges` then it wouldn't still really matter?

Comment: Not really. There are different roles and different usage for every lifecycle hook.
For example:
NgOnInit: angular calls this method, so your code will be called once, when the component loads, you can use this hook, to fetch initial data from the server for example.
NgOnChanges: angular calls this method every time when an input change happens, you can use this hook to check the previous state whit the current one for example.
And so on for every lifecycle hook, there is a use case. Check the docs to make sure what is the role of each hook.

Comment: And the change detection is happening automatically, but you can change this behavior, there is 3 option you can use. Default, OnPush, and totally off and do manually.
The default strategy automatically detects all the changes, it checks the DOM every time and looks for a change. The OnPush strategy works with NGRX, it tells Angular when to check for changes. And then you can turn the detection off, and do it by yourself by manually calling the detection method. https://angular.io/guide/change-detection-skipping-subtrees#using-onpush

Answer (score 1):

As you can see in this desctiption the answer is **no**.

[image]

The `NgInit()` function is only called **once** after the first `ngOnChages()`. It's kind of a "constructor-hook" (it really isnt a constructor though). It is only called once on the initialization / first render of the component.

If this isn't the behaviour you're looking for, then the image also provides an explanation for every other hook - there you'll find the one you need.

Comment: Well for instance, when I change `ingredients` , do you perhaps know how `ngOnInIt` knows how to update the new value of `ingredients`?